# Coupon code not working on special price

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, coupon-codes

Shopping cart price rule coupon code not working with special price i.e. those products who have special price not applying coupon code. It is giving a error 'Coupon code "xxxxx" is not valid'.

Comment: Please share more information, like which version of magento, any custom modules installed for promotions, a screen shot of Shopping cart price rule